# Dummy filters in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

How do I make a dummy filter query in Django (a filter that is always matched) and an exclude query that is never matched.  The reason is because I have cases where my query is None, and in those cases I want to use a dummy filter.  This is the code:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(filterQuery).exclude(excludeQuery)
```

In cases where `filterQuery` or `excludeQuery` is `None` I get an error, so I want to add the following conditional before that query:

```
if filterQuery == None: filterQuery = ???
if excludeQuery == None: excludeQuery = ???
MyModel.objects.filter(filterQuery).exclude(excludeQuery)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only filter/exclude when you need to, instead of using empty statement, do this:

```
found = MyModel.objects.all()
if filterQuery:
    found = found.filter(filterQuery)
if excludeQuery:
    found = found.exclude(excludeQuery)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a dict, particularly if you have complex filters.

```
filterQuery = excludeQuery = {}

# optionally set the filters based on some logic
if 1==1:
  filterQuery['agent'] = 'John'

if 2==2:
  excludeQuery['user_id__in'] = [1, 2]

if 3==3:
  filterQuery['time__gte'] = timezone.now()

MyModel.objects.filter(**filterQuery).exclude(**excludeQuery)
```

You could add some ifs like Shang suggested to see if you need to apply the filter or not, but I doubt there is much of a performance loss and this is much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to my answer above is to use Q() expressions, particularly if you need and/or logic:

```
filterQuery = Q()

filterQuery = filterQuery | Q(agent='John')
filterQuery = filterQuery & Q(time__gte=timezone.now())

...

MyModel.objects.filter(filterQuery)
```